# Joomla CMS and ZEND code

Tags: php, zend-framework, joomla

I write component to joomla cms and I need to use zend code to google calendar. I write new class to organize operation, but I have problem with zend.

My code class is:

```
<?php
// Protect from unauthorized access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');


// Load framework base classes

$zend_library_path = 'helpers/library/Zend';
set_include_path ( JPATH_ROOT . PATH_SEPARATOR . $zend_library_path);
//include ('Json.php');

//echo JPATH_ROOT . PATH_SEPARATOR . $zend_library_path;
 include_once('Loader.php');
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . 'tables');



class GoogleCalendar
{
```

I have warming:

```
Warning: include_once(Loader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/samba
```

What I have to change to it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the `zend` directory in Joomla!'s `libraries` directory. That's what it is made for. Then, you import the Zend autoloader.

```
<?php
// Protect from unauthorized access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

// Init the Joomla! framework here!

// Load autoloader for Zend
jimport('zend.loader');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

// Load framework base classes
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/tables');

class GoogleCalendar
{
```

Everything else should work magically.

Comment: but how load zend class?  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about that Zend_Loader does not automatically register its autoload function. Correcting my answer accordingly.

Comment: probably I done something wrong. I copy all files from liberary ZEND to 'liberaries' JOOMLA and I have them directory 'Zend'. Next I add jimport('Zend.Loader'); But when I want to use sth like Zend_Loader::registerAutoload(); I have error : Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader' not found

Comment: Try this one: `JLoader::registerPrefix('Zend_', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/Zend');` instead of `jimport('zend.loader');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific with your include function:

```
set_include_path ( JPATH_ROOT . PATH_SEPARATOR . $zend_library_path);
```

parhaps:

```
set_include_path ( JPATH_ROOT . PATH_SEPARATOR . JPATH_COMPONENT .'/'. $zend_library_path .'/');
```